# Target class [db.schema] does not exist After upgrading to Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, service-provider

After upgrading from Laravel 8 to 9, I get stuck on this error

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
>
> Target class [db.schema] does not exist.
>
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:895

any idea the cause and how to fix ? thanks !

Going through the upgrade guide nothing is said about any changes to the `DatabaseServiceProvider` or `ServiceProviders` in general

Comment: did you change the version of nunomaduro/collision to ^6.1 like pointed out in the upgrade guide ?

Comment: @N69S yes it's updated to ^6.1